# Typescript const Enum issue

Tags: typescript

I have declared the following enum in my Typescript file:

```
export const enum INPUT_PATTERNS{
    ALL          = ".*",
    ONLY_NUMBERS = "[0-9]*"

}
```

During compilation, I keep on getting the following error message:

> **In 'const' enum declarations member initializer must be constant expression.**

I have initialized the enums with constant values and so I dont understand whats wrong here?

Secondly, if I remove the const identifier from enum as follows:

```
export enum INPUT_PATTERNS{
    ALL          = ".*",
    ONLY_NUMBERS = "[0-9]*"

}
```

then I get the following error:

> **Type '".*"' is not assignable to type 'INPUT_PATTERNS'.***
>   **Type '"[0-9]"' is not assignable to type 'INPUT_PATTERNS'.**

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1206

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```js
export enum INPUT_PATTERNS{
    ALL          = <any>".*",
    ONLY_NUMBERS = <any>"[0-9]*" 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Enums allow us to define a set of named numeric constants. http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html

You can use a combination of namespace and const variables:

```
export namespace INPUT_PATTERNS {
    export const ALL = ".*";
    export const ONLY_NUMBERS = "[0-9]*";
}
```